# Problem with pushButton handling - pyqgis

Tags: pyqgis, events, pyqt

I have made a pushButton - new window relation. Now, when I'm trying to 'link' methods with pushButtons in new window they don't react.

Here is what I wrote in metod, which opens new window in plugin:

```
def handleButton(self):
    self.sc = PluginConfigDialog()
    self.sc.show()
    result = self.sc.exec_()
```

I have also added this line in __init__:

```
self.dlg.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.handleButton)
```

But when I'm trying to add a alike action with a pushButton_2 in new window, to open another one (third window) nothing happens. Here is code I wrote:

```
def handleEdit(self):
    self.s = PluginEditDialog()
    self.s.show()
    result = self.s.exec_()
```

I also added this line to __init__:

```
self.d.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.handleEdit)
```

I have also added imports for this new windows and create the dialogs (after translation) and keep reference in __init__

Do you know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is `self.d.pushButton_2` (instead of `self.dlg.pushButton_2`) a typo? This might be the cause of your issue.

Comment: It's not a typo. There are two dialogs in \__init__:
# Create the dialog (after translation) and keep reference
        self.dlg = PluginDialog()
        self.d = PluginConfigDialog()
I'm not sure but if I want to refer to pushButton in second plugindialog I must import it and create a dialog and keep reference to it in \__init__

Comment: @W.Tom You can also write the listener before the line _self.s.show()_

Comment: @eftas Sorry, but I'm not into pyqgis and I don't understand what will it change?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8763339/4699904

Answer (score 1):

Here is my approach for solving this:

- In your main file import the class which creates the dialog

  ```
  from style_manager import StyleManagerDialog
  ```
- connect to a button which opens the new window

  ```
  # in the init function of the main class
  self.dlg.mv_pb_styles.clicked.connect(self.t1_load_styles)

  self.sub_dlg = StyleManagerDialog(self.iface)

  def t1_load_styles(self):
      self.sub_dlg.show()
      res = self.sub_dlg.exec_()
  ```
- In the class which creates the new dialog import qgis modules and connect to the  QGIS iface

  ```
  from qgis.core import *
  from qgis.gui import *
  from qgis.utils import *

  class StyleManagerDialog(QtGui.QDialog, FORM_CLASS):
      def __init__(self, iface, parent=None):
         """Constructor."""
        super(VortexStyleManagerDialog, self).__init__(parent)
        self.iface = iface
        self.setupUi(self)
  ```
- in the class which creates the dialog connect to your buttons and write the functions

  ```
  self.button.clicked.connect(self.style_set_file)
  def style_set_file(self):
      filename = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, u"Do Stuff!", "", "QGIS Style (*.qml);;Text (*.txt);;XML(*.xml);; All files(*.*)")
     # do something with a qgis layer 
     print self.iface.activeLayer().name()
  ```

I have tested this approach for QGIS 2.14.15 and it works as from me intended.